# Filter the dataframe by having only the rows that are month apart from each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

```
Date    Latitude    Longitude   Disaster
2011-01-10  56.79   89.90   Cyclone
2011-02-09  45.01   79.24   Cyclone
2010-11-20  34.08   69.92   Cyclone
2010-12-19  66.78   125.35  Cyclone
2017-09-10  56.99   98.22   Cyclone
```

I have a dataframe that I need to filter it so that it **contains data about where have cyclonic activity occurred repeatedly within a one-month time frame**.
I used merge operation to find pairs of cyclones occurring in the same location-

```
merged_df = df.merge(df, on= ["Longitude","Latitude"], how ="inner")
```

I was able to find the data within a month for a particular date, say: 2002-01-01, using

`df[dt['Date'] >= date(2002,1,1)  & df['Date'] < date(2002,1,1) + relativedelta(months=1)].count()`.

but am unable to figure out how should I apply it to the entire dataframe so that it gives me information about where have cyclonic activity occurred repeatedly within a one-month time frame. Can somebody help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the memory, `merge` with itself and then filter after the merge to only those cyclones that occur within 1 month. Use `pd.offsets.DateOffset` to get the same logic as `relativedelta`

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df[df.Disaster=='Cyclone'].reset_index()  # Need index to deduplicate later

merged = df.merge(df, on='Disaster', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])

mask = ((merged.index_1 > merged.index_2)  # Remove self merges and AB-BA duplicates
        & merged.Date_1.between(merged.Date_2 - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1), 
                                merged.Date_2 + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)))

merged = merged[mask].drop(columns=['index_1', 'index_2'])
```

#### Output: `merged`

```
       Date_1  Latitude_1  Longitude_1 Disaster     Date_2  Latitude_2  Longitude_2
5  2011-02-09       45.01        79.24  Cyclone 2011-01-10       56.79        89.90
15 2010-12-19       66.78       125.35  Cyclone 2011-01-10       56.79        89.90
17 2010-12-19       66.78       125.35  Cyclone 2010-11-20       34.08        69.92
```

---

If you truly just need the rows from the original DataFrame and the pairings are useless, then don't drop `['index_1', 'index_2']` and use the unique values to subset the original `DataFrame`, or use `pd.wide_to_long` on `merged` + `drop_duplicates` to format it back to how the original looked.

Comment: Since I need where to have cyclonic activity occurred repeatedly within a one-month time frame, should I not apply the merge on Latitude and Longitude for the same location.

Comment: @Basileus I'm not doing any merging on latitude or longitude. I'm simply merging on `Disaster`, which in this case only creates every single pair-wise combination of two cyclones, regardless of anything else. So if you have a `DataFrame` with 900 cyclones, the resulting merge will be 810,000 rows. You can see in my output `DataFrame` the latitude and longitudes of the two cyclones are very different.

Comment: Also, your comment indicates that what you actually want may be very different from how you worded your question title. If you simply need to figure out if more than one cyclone happened in `November 2012` then that's far easier. But doing a calendar month rolling operation is much harder. It becomes very easy if you instead specify a month as say 31 days.